# How can i change a lowercase string to an uppercase string and also first letter capitalized on a commodore 64?

Tags: commodore

I have entered "hello world" on a commodore 64 emulator. I have to make it print out as 
hello world
HELLO WORLD
Hello World

How can I do this using only one print statement?

Comment: Add the BASIC comand you write

Answer (score 3):

Here's an answer, with explanation below

```
10 a$="hello world" : rem your string goes here
20 c$=a$:gosub100:d$=a$:gosub200:printc$;" ";a$;" ";d$ : rem the one print
30 end
100 a0$=a$:a$="" :a2$=" ":rem in capital-case subroutine
110 for i=1tolen(a0$):a1$=mid$(a0$,i,1):ifa2$=" "thena1$=chr$(asc(a1$)or128)
120 a2$=a1$:a$=a$+a1$:next:return
200 a0$=a$:a$="": rem all in uppercase subroutine
210 for i=1tolen(a0$):a1$=mid$(a0$,i,1):a$=a$+chr$(asc(a1$)or128):next:return
```

It meets your rule for having only one print statement.
It works by making a copy of the all lower-case string, then converting to first-letter case and making a copy of that, and finally converting the rest to upper case, and then using the copies in the correct order in the single print statement.

Capitalizing in PETSCII is otherwise pretty simple, since you only have to set the high bit (128) on each character to do so.  Since BASIC 2.0 does not already have functions for this, however, subroutines that operate on a$ were required.

Answer (score 0):

You can use control characters in your strings and print statements. Some of these are documented in the C64 BASIC Manual and Programmers Reference Guide (i.e., the reverse characters, and also colour character codes with the `CTRL` and `C=` key)

Here's a quick example (had to screen shot to show it) - when you open a string, press `CRTL` and `N` - it will show a reversed N character, this switch from CBM Graphics characters and CBM Business Mode characters. Pressing `CTRL` and `H` will add a reversed `H` in the string, this is to disable the `SHIFT` + `C=` key to stop you manually switching between these two character modes. Leave this out if you want an easy way to switch between *Business Mode* and *Graphics Mode*.

As far as I know, there is no simple control character to switch from Business Mode to Graphics Mode that you can use in an open string as described here. To switch back to Graphics Mode, use:

`print chr$(142)`

This can also be *added to* a string, i.e.,

`let a$ = chr$(142) + "hello world"`

You also don't need the `LET` statement in Commodore BASIC. I've used it here for illustrative purposes only.

Source: [PETSCII - C64-Wiki](https://www.c64-wiki.com/wiki/PETSCII)

[image: PRINTing a string with control characters - image 1]

[image: The results when running the program exapmle - image 2]